# How can I disable javascript errors on "TWebbrowser"?

Tags: delphi, alerts, twebbrowser

I am getting javascript errors popping up in some webpages I am browsing to.

Does anyone know how to disable javascript error boxes from displaying in a Delphi app using a TWebbrowser?  or any other messageboxes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to set `WebBrowser1.Silent := True`

Comment: Yes this solution solved the problem, but it also disable all message coming from the TwebBrowser like user name popup!

Comment: @Mario, what is a user name popup?