# How to suppress Script error warnings when using TWebBrowser in Delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi, scripting, twebbrowser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to disable javascript errors on “twebbrowser” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722060/how-to-disable-javascript-errors-on-twebbrowser)

I'm using the TWebBrowser component with Delphi 6.0 to display a YouTube web page.  Sometimes I get a Script error message box from Internet Explorer, which TWebBrowser embeds, complaining that an error has occurred in a script running on the page and prompting me "Yes or No" to disable further execution of any scripts on the page.

I want to be able to suppress all Script warning boxes since certain web pages act funny in the TWebBrowser component.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `Silent` property to `True`