# Chrome/ Firefox Alternative to TWebBrowser Control

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

I have a Delphi app that shows a group of webpages in a TWebBrowser control.  Its a kiosk type app so a user touches a button on the side and it shows a particular webpage in a tab.  I am having some problems with certain sites and getting IE javscript errors.

I would like to know if there is a way I can embed a chrome or firefox browser in a tab or on a form from Delphi?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722060/how-to-disable-javascript-errors-on-twebbrowser) seems to answer the issue I had with getting javascript errors.

Comment: you could also just move up to modern IE

Comment: Surely it uses the ie that's on the box?  I have the most up to date.

Comment: IE6 (what XP shipped with) is pretty poor at Javascript. IE9 is much better. Which IE do you have?

Comment: David, I assume it uses the IE on the box, which is IE8.  I get Javascript errors.  Perhaps there is an incorrect setting somewhere.

Comment: see this answer for FF alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162718/how-to-embed-a-browser-object-other-than-ien-in-a-delphi-application

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I should have googled first. Found this

http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/

Took a little bit of fiddling, but seems to work good.

Direct link to the archive download page: https://code.google.com/archive/p/delphichromiumembedded/downloads
Because the Google Code page is closed

Comment: I also tested it. It works well! (Don't forget to deploy the DLL with your app)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that IE8 raise random javascript errors with TWebBrowser. We are also in the process to change to Chromium component.

Comment: Too bad they don't have a direct download link (they have svn).

Comment: How to execute javascript directly using TChromium?